# Where to find the folderId of a mail folder from Outlook

Tags: graph, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I need the folder ID of a folder of a mail account we use to fetch emails from programmatically. Now we use the Graph API and only want emails from a specific folder. I tried some settings in Outlook but couldn't find it. Also when I open Outlook in the browser I can't find it.

Now I've tried the Graph API Explorer, but I don't have sufficient permissions to get data from the mail account due to corporate bla bla.

Anyone have a golden tip?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which endpoint have you tried but when you call one of the following endpoints

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders
```

Endpoint returns a collection of [mailFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0) including folder id

You can filter the specific folder by its `displayName`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$filter=displayName eq '{folder_name}'
```

If you need list child folder you can call this endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{folder_id}/childFolders
```

Comment: hi , would you know if there is some documentation on using these end point with some examples. I want to create a mail in the draft folder of a shared mailbox. thanks in advance.